# NameError with LESS CSS

Tags: css, less

This is a my experience problem.

Problem is I am using `LESS` CSS and when compile them into `CSS` it is compiling, but there are some "NameError" message/s.

Just I used gradient color in my custom.less file, like this

```
> .section {
    float: left;
    width : 64%;
    margin-right: 2%;

    > .box {
        #gradient.vertical(#efefef; #ffffff; 5%; 70%);              
        max-height: 200px;

    }
}
```

When compile it I can get like this error message, but my gradient is working - 
[image]

**NOTE :** I have saved my file with `UTF-8 without BOM` and I use a third party compiler named `winless` to compile my `LESS` files.

Can anybody tell why is this happening?

Comment: Can you show your full less file? Have you `@import`ed all dependent less files?

Comment: Yes I have imported all dependent files

Comment: This is full code of my custom.less - http://pastebin.com/4YLsXTdi

Comment: I have imported these files to my `main.less` file properly and its compiling correctly.

Comment: my less file convert css.. but display NameErrors when compiling

Answer (score 0):

t looks like the LESS compiler is silently failing if files are encoded with a BOM. (That's a Byte Order Mark for those not familiar with the term.) This is the default setting in some editors, such as Visual Studio.

The compiler barfs up an error on the BOM if it's in your root file, but seems to fail silently for @import-ed files.

Try saving your files as UTF-8 without a BOM, and see if that solves your problem.

Comment: Before I ask here, I tried it but problem is still have

Comment: I am using Sublime Text as my text editor. It is saving files as UTF-8 without BOM by default.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
.section {
    float: left;
    width : 64%;
    margin-right: 2%;

    > .box {
        #gradient > .vertical(#efefef; #ffffff; 5%; 70%);              
        max-height: 200px;
    }
}
```

Comment: try this code putting there `.section {
    float: left;
    width : 64%;
    margin-right: 2%;

    > .box {
        #gradient > .vertical(#efefef; #ffffff; 5%; 70%);              
        max-height: 200px;
    }
}`

Comment: Error is - `Error: #gradient.vertical is undefined`

Comment: Are you also importing `mixins.less`?